# Dynamically load svg, change it and insert into document

Tags: javascript, svg

I need to load svg file, change it (rotate and change color of some paths) and then display it on the webpage without any external libraries, just with plain JS. I've tried this code from MDN but have no idea how to access an SVG object to manipulate SVG elements:

```
window.onload=run;

function run()
{

    loadSvg("/img/dgt.svg");

}

function loadSvg(url)
{
    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange=function()
    {   if(req.readyState == 4)
        {   if(req.status == 200)
            {   var res=req.responseText;
                draw(res);
            }
            else
            {   console.log("URL "+url+" not available");
            }
        }
    }
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send();
}

function draw(svgData)
{
    var c=document.getElementById("ctr");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var DOMURL=window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    var img=new Image();
    var svg=new Blob([svgData], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url=DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

    img.onload=function()
        {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    img.src=url;
}
```

So, what I'd like to achieve:
1) Load swg as a string and convert it to the SVG element, or just load it as an SVG element
2) Do some changes, especially a rotations and fills/colors changes
3) Draw SVG on the webpage, either on canvas or just append it as the image/swg

How can it be done?
Thank you

Comment: In what way does it fail? What does yor debugger reveal?

Comment: Nothing. It just does not draw anything without any errors. I'll try to make a fiddle now

Comment: Single stepping an a debugger cannot reveal nothing. Does draw get called? Does the onreadystatechange function get called etc.

Comment: Just checked it once more and now it works! But I swear, it did not a hour before! )) So, it's my fault. Have no idea how it happened.  

Anyway, since it is an image, how can I change svg in it? I need it to be an svg element instead, I suppose? Cannot realize how to do that... I could rotate it as an image, but, since it's not in the DOM, I cannot access SVG elements, for example by getElementById()?

Comment: Perhaps you should delete this question and ask a new one.

Comment: Why, it would be almost the same, maybe I could just edit this one?

Comment: It seems unlikely the existing answer would apply to your new question which would be a problem.

Comment: But the main question was "how to do that" and "what steps to perform"?

Comment: I actually want same...Could u share some references..how u have implemented this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AngularJS implementation.
Store the desired SVG path elements as a raster file (say ***new-dgt.svg***). For example:

```
{
    "home" : "s.o.m.e.p.a.t.h",
    "facebook" : "s.o.m.e.o.t.h.e.r.p.a.t.h"
}
```

Create a directive/component, say ***svg-loader*** which takes path parameter as attribute, will search and return path from our raster file ***new-dgt.svg*** and put it into the desired template. Preferably, make service to make the AJAX call for the file.

Comment: Thank you, but it shall be done without any libraries, just with plain js